# Android night mode reduce text size automatically?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I've made a strange observation if I switch between day and night mode with

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

and

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

all of my texts getting slightly but noticeable smaller in night mode and return back to the previous size when switching back to day mode. Is there some implicit rule applied?

Answer (score 0):

> Does it happen when using the system switch?

If so it may be a slight inconsistency in your XML layouts otherwise it maybe something related to the way you switched night mode with code.